# How to prove there does not exist a fundamental Pythagorean triple with hypotenuse 195?

Tags: number-theory

Everyone! How can I prove there does not exist a fundamental Pythagorean triple with hypotenuse 195? I know hypotenuse can be written as x^2+y^2. (because a fundamental Pythagorean triple is of the form(x^2−y^2,2xy,x^2+y^2))However, how can I come from there to show x^2+y^2 cannot equal to 195?

Comment: @dxiv I think OP is using the fact that a fundamental Pythageorean triple is of the form $(x^2 - y^2, 2xy, x^2 + y^2)$ (or with the first two reversed) for some $x,y$.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! It is a genius way to look into this problem!

Comment: @dxiv, sorry for the confusion. Daniel helped me explain my idea.

Comment: @dxiv I guess the letters I chose (x, y) created confusions. Because they are normally used to demonstrate x^2+y^2=z^2. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

$195 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and all squares are $0$ or $1 \pmod 4$

Answer (score 0):

It clearer to write $[x,y,z] = [a^2-b^2,2ab,a^2+b^2]$ is a fundamental or primitive solution of $z^2=x^2+y^2$. Prove that $z=a^2+b^2$ cannot equal $195$

$195 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ cannot be equal to the sum of two non-zero squares, which are all  $0$,$1$ or $2 \pmod{4}$. This is proved by first showing that all squares are $0$ or $1\pmod{4}$.